# how to change the value of UIPageViewControllerOptionInterPageSpacingKey?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, ios8, uipageviewcontroller

i am trying to set the value  `UIPageViewControllerOptionInterPageSpacingKey` in `ViewDidAppear()`

but my initialization code of UIPageViewController is in `ViewDidLoad()`

there is a problem in autolayout if i set the `UIPageViewControllerOptionInterPageSpacingKey` before the View set it's layout

Answer (score 3):

You must change the page spacing at initialization. This can be done in the XIB/Storyboard or with the `initWithTransitionStyle:navigationOrientation:options:` method passing `@{UIPageViewControllerOptionInterPageSpacingKey : @(5.f)}`. This is mentioned in the `UIPageViewController.h` file [from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Options_Keys):

```
// Key for specifying spacing between pages in options dictionary argument to initWithTransitionStyle:navigationOrientation:options:.
// Value should be a CGFloat wrapped in an NSNumber. Default is '0'.
// Only valid for use with page view controllers with transition style 'UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll'.
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString * const UIPageViewControllerOptionInterPageSpacingKey NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);
```